# HashMap implementation optimization

Tags: c++, data-structures, hashmap

I have a hashmap containing about half a million entries the key is a string whose values comes as a combination of 5 different inputs. (string concatenation) the domain of each of the input is small but the combination of the 5 inputs gives this huge map (500K items). Now I am thinking of optimizing this structure.

My idea is to hash the input (the combination of 5 inputs) by hashing each individual input and combining that 5 hashes into one single hash (int 32 or 64) and then look up that hash.

My question is there a known data structure that can handle this situation well? and Is it worth doing that optimization? I wanna optimize both memory and run-time.

I am using `C++` and `std::unordered_map` the key is the combined string from the 5 inputs and the output is random. I didn't find any relation between the inputs and outputs (random or serial).

```
125 458 699 sadsadasd 5  => 56.
125 458 699 sadsadasd 3  => 57.
125 458 699 sadsadasd 4  => 58.
125 458 699 sadsadasd 5  => 25.
125 458 699 gsdfsds 3  => 89.
```

The domain of each of the inputs is small (the 4th input has 2K different values while the other inputs can have about only 20 different values).

Comment: What do you mean by "data structure"? Are you looking for a good function to combine several hash values into a single hash?

Comment: Is hashing the concatenation really that different than hashing the 5 inputs and then combining them somehow? What makes you think this will be more optimal?

Comment: @Sneftel maybe other data-structure like a tree or a hashing function, my plan is to use 5 hash maps for each input to get 5 hashes and then combine the 5 hashes into one hash. but is there other data structure? and is this optimization worth doing?

Comment: @Dave this will optimize memory by having the key only int32 instead of string which i think will consume more memory.

Comment: I don't undestand. Could you make an example of what those 5 inputs do?

Comment: If the look-ups are too slow, it might not be because of the hashing at all. String concatenation can be costly, if the strings are a known size before hand, consider butting them into a fixed length container and hashing on that.

Comment: @mmohab if you are using `unordered_map` it should be hashing the string for you... to a `size_t`.

Comment: @Dave yes true and working fine but I am wondering if there is a room for optimization :) actually I am looking more for memory optimization.

Comment: @mmohab can you please explain why hashing 125 458 699 sadsadasd 5 in your example first time gives 56 and next time it gives 59?

Comment: @mmohab also what is the rationale that makes you thinking hash(A) + hash(B) will be better than hash(AB) ?

Comment: I would also compare a tree-based container. Sometimes, the time to compute the hash values consumes more time than doing comparison, especially for strings where a comparison often does not need to process the whole string.

Comment: Actually I will still think about a way of combining the hashes probably I will not use addition, my main goal is to optimize memory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [GNU perf](https://www.gnu.org/software/gperf/) to generate a perfect hash function for your keys.

Comment: +1 for GNU perf, will be useful for my case because I already have the keys.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that there is no way to reduce the size of your keys that will result in reliable extraction. Hashing the 5 inputs into 1 integer is a one-way function that will prevent you from performing reliable lookups.

The way round this would be to keep a translation table, but that's actually more overhead because each distinct tuple of inputs would require the storage for 2 hashes and the tuple.

I think you're best off using a `std::tuple<int, int, int, std::string, int>` as the key type in  a single map.

If you use a `std::map<tuple<>, data_type>` you won't need to provide a hashing function. If you stay with the `unordered_map`, you'll need to provide one since `std::tuple` has no default `hash<>` specialisation.